# display Json nested arrays in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I've written one JSON script with nested arrays and trying to display the all the data based on title. but unfortunately i couldn't make that happen. i'm placing my JSON and powershell code below. kindly help me.

JSON code:

```
{
  "Deploy": {
    "ENV": "DIT",
    "Servers": [
      {
        "Webservers": [
          {
            "Server": ["Server1","Server2"],
            "site": ["website1","WebSite2"],
            "VDIR": ["WebSite1","WebSite2"]
          },
          {
            "Server": ["Server1","Server2"],
            "site": ["WebSite1","WebSite2"],
            "VDIR": ["WebSite1","WebSite2"]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Winservers": [
          {
            "Server": ["Server1","Server2"],
            "winService": ["service1","service2"]
          },
          {
            "Server": ["Server3","Server4"],
            "winService": ["service3","service4"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Powershell Code:

```
$Deploy=(Get-Content D:\Deploy.json -Raw) -join "`n"|ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($i in $Deploy.Deploy.Servers) {
    $s=($i | Get-Member -MemberType *property).Name
    Write-host "$s" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    foreach($j in $s) {
        $items=($i.$j|Get-Member -MemberType *property).Name
        Write-host "$items" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        foreach($k in $items) {
            $z=($j.$k | Get-Member -MemberType *property).Name
            Write-host "$z" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    }
}
```

Current result is :

```
Webservers
Server site VDIR
Winservers
Server winService
```

But expected result should be like below:

```
Webservers:
Server:                      Sites:            VDIR:
list of servers              list of sites      list of VDIR

Server:                      Sites:            VDIR:
list of servers              list of sites      list of VDIR
Winservers:
Server:                      services:            
list of servers              list of sites
```

Kindly help ... i'm trying by best in different ways but none of one gave expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I think your problem can be solved with next way.

```
$ht, $src = @{}, 'D:\sandbox\source.xml'
($srv = (Get-Content $src | ConvertFrom-Json).Deploy.Servers).ForEach{
   $name = $_.PSObject.Properties.Name
   $ht[$name] = $srv.$name
}

Write-Host Webservers -ForegroundColor Yellow
$ht.Webservers | Out-String

Write-Host Winservers -ForegroundColor Yellow
$ht.Winservers | Out-String
```

Comment: Hi Greg,i've tried in the above way but no luck. i'm not sure whether you have tested or not. as because "Servers" tab contains nested array. inside of each element has nested arrays. hence it was not giving data.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thank you so much for the response.i can able to get the values as expected. but i want the result like Webservers --> server (title)--(list of servers)  ,sites (title)--(list of items, vdir(title) -- (list of of items)like wise other elements. as because i've to use there values in different places in my script. kindly give your suggestion --Thanks, Siva

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is just a formatted output, maybe this is more to your liking

```
$deploy = Get-Content 'D:\Deploy.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Host "Webservers:`r`n-----------"
$items = @()
foreach ($server in $deploy.Deploy.Servers.Webservers) {
    foreach ($item in $server) {
        $items += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
            Server = @($item.Server) -join ', '
            Sites  = @($item.site) -join ', '
            VDIR   = @($item.VDIR) -join ', '
        })
    }
}
$items | Out-String

Write-Host "Winservers:`r`n-----------"
$items = @()
foreach ($server in $deploy.Deploy.Servers.Winservers) {
    foreach ($item in $server) {
        $items += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
            Server = @($item.Server) -join ', '
            WinService  = @($item.winService) -join ', '
        })
    }
}
$items | Out-String
```

The output will look like this:

```
Webservers:
-----------

Server           Sites              VDIR              
------           -----              ----              
Server1, Server2 website1, WebSite2 WebSite1, WebSite2
Server1, Server2 WebSite1, WebSite2 WebSite1, WebSite2



Winservers:
-----------

Server           WinService        
------           ----------        
Server1, Server2 service1, service2
Server3, Server4 service3, service4
```

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic for-display-only solution that doesn't output the exact format you describe, but is concise (PSv3+):

```
(Get-Content -Raw D:\Deploy.json | ConvertFrom-Json).Deploy.Servers |
  ForEach-Object {
    $serverTypePropName = $_.psobject.properties.Name
    Write-Host "${serverTypePropName}:"
    $_.$serverTypePropName | Format-Table
  }
```

- `(Get-Content -Raw D:\Deploy.json | ConvertFrom-Json)` converts the JSON input to custom objects.
- `.Deploy.Server` accesses the array-valued property whose elements are the objects whose `Webservers` and `Winservers` properties, respectively, contain the server-details sub-arrays.
- In the `ForEach-Object` script block:

  - `$_.psobject.properties.Name` extracts the name of the one property (`Webservers` or `Winservers`) of each input object that contains the array of server details.
  - `$_.$serverTypePropName | Format-Table` accesses that property and renders the server-details array as a table.
    Note that *explicit* use of `Format-Table` is needed, because the server-detail arrays have different property structures between the `Webservers` and the `Winservers` object; without an explicit formatting/output command, only the *first* array's properties would render.

With your sample input, the above yields:

```
Webservers:

Server             site                 VDIR
------             ----                 ----
{Server1, Server2} {website1, WebSite2} {WebSite1, WebSite2}
{Server1, Server2} {WebSite1, WebSite2} {WebSite1, WebSite2}


Winservers:

Server             winService
------             ----------
{Server1, Server2} {service1, service2}
{Server3, Server4} {service3, service4}
```